# sqlite query due date

Tags: sql, sqlite, date

I am trying to make a query in sqlite where it shows invoices that has passed their due date. 
I tried:

```
SELECT i.invoice_ID AS 'Invoice ID', i.due_date AS 'Due Date', i.invoice_total_amount AS 'Invoice Total'
FROM invoice as i 
WHERE date(due_date) > date('now');
```

But that doesn't work. How can I do this correctly?

UPDATE:

My table only contains:

```
INSERT INTO invoice VALUES (1, 1, 1, 2007-02-01, 2007-02-27, 10028);
```

The result og my query is: 
[image]

Comment: Please clarify: 1. What is your table look like. 2. What does "doesn't work" mean? Syntax error? Wrong data returned?

Comment: Hint:  Date Due would be less than now.

Comment: Hint: why are you subtracting numbers in your insert statement?

Comment: You are using single quotes where you shouldn't: the aliases of the columns (better use backticks or square brackets) and you don't use single quotes where you should: for dates like `'2007-02-01'`.

Comment: @Shawn  - the really interesting quetsion is, why isn't the result 1970 instead of 1978?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are querying for due date greater than now; which means the reverse (invoces that did NOT pass their due date)

use `WHERE date(due_date) < date('now');`

**UPDATE:**

As per update in question, you're inserting your values wrong. You are trying to use [Text format for date](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_data_types.htm), but you aren't quoting it, so instead you end up using integer format. Instead, quote to get text:

```
INSERT INTO invoice VALUES (1, 1, 1, '2007-02-01', '2007-02-27', 10028);
```

Comment: Yes, I understand that. Please see the update, I am still not getting a correct result

Comment: I eventually understood what you meant and solved it. Thank you

Comment: SQL uses single quotes for strings,btw.